# How I can share my Virtual Machine with other people

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

I've set a Virtual Machine and installed on that some tools, now I've to share it with other people that will install it and have the same environment , Its enough that I share my folder? I've used VirtualBox to create it.

Comment: What did you use to create that VM? Virtualbox? KVM? You need to include this in your question.

Comment: Included, VirtualBox

Answer (score 0):

**Virtualbox** vm's work on any computer unless you have changed advanced settings, like enabling more than one CPU core for use with the vm for example. You have to make sure that the new computer can handle those changes and that it has the memory required to run the vm successfully.

I am constantly using vm's on more than one computers, just by copying the directory that has the name of the vm to the new computer's designated Virtualbox vm directory and adding the vm to that computer's virtualbox.

Just check if everything, like network or audio adapters have been detected correctly in the vm settings, after you add it to the new computer's Virtualbox that is, and if something doesn't look right, change it before running the vm.

Comment: Thank you, so enough  just to share the folder, nice to know.